# Perform insert query on a Go-routine

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, gocql

Below is the query using `gocql` driver:

```
    insertQueryString = "INSERT INTO my_table (id_1, id_2, textDetails) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?) IF NOT EXISTS"
    cassandra.Session.Query(insertQueryString, 
    id1,                            
    id2,        
    myTextDetails).Exec();
```

---

Table schema in Cassandra 3.0 is:

```
CREATE      TABLE  IF    NOT    EXISTS my_table (
  id_1                   UUID,
  id_2                   UUID,
  textDetails            TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_1, id_2)
);
```

---

We have a scenario for above `INSERT` query initiated on multiple Go-routines(http handler) with same column value combination of `(id_1, id_2)`,
then,

Does Cassandra ensures that only first
`INSERT` operation is executed successfully? and errors out the subsequent `INSERT` requests with existing value combination of `(id_1, id_2)` in database

Answer (score 1):

There's a common saying with regard to unique PRIMARY KEYs and concurrent operations in Cassandra:

"Last write wins."

> Does Cassandra ensures that only first INSERT operation is executed successfully? and errors out the subsequent INSERT requests with existing value combination of (id_1, id_2) in database

Usually, no.  Cassandra typically ensures that *all* operations for a particular PRIMARY KEY(s) will be executed successfully.

However, in this case whereby using a [lightweight transaction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html), the answer is "yes."  In this case, the first write which makes it in will "win," and the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause will prevent the other from writes from succeeding.

FYI - You'll take a bit of a hit in performance, as a lightweight transaction makes multiple round trips to the database.